# C# List Generic Extension Method vs Non-Generic

Tags: c#, generics, collections

This is a simple question (I hope), there are generic and non-generic methods in collection classes like `List<T>` that have methods such as `Where` and `Where<T>`.

Example:

```
        List<int> numbers = new List<int>()
        {
            1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
        };

        IEnumerable<int> evens = numbers.Where((x) =>
        {
            return x % 2 == 0;
        });

        IEnumerable<int> evens2 = numbers.Where<int>((x) =>
        {
            return x % 2 == 0;
        });
```

Why use one over the other (Generic or Non-Generic)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They're the same method (documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx)). The type parameter portion after the method name (i.e. `<int>` in this case) is optional when the compiler is able to infer the type automatically and unambiguously from context. In this case, the method is being applied to an object implementing the interface `IEnumerable<int>` (i.e. the object `numbers` of type `List<int>`) from which the compiler can safely infer that the type parameter is `int`.

Note, also, that `Where<T>` is actually an *extension method* on the `System.Linq.Enumerable` class which can be applied to objects of any class implementing `IEnumerable<T>` such as `List<T>`.